# Passing arguments to a .sty-file - a specific case

Tags: package-writing, optional-arguments, package-options, key-value, xkeyval

After having plowed through (i.e. read and trimmed down the given examples in an attempt to apply them to my case) these documentations and guides:

- [Implementing key-value input: An introduction](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf)
- [The kvoptions package](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvoptions.pdf)
- [pgfopts — LaTeX package options with pgfkeys](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pgfopts/pgfopts.pdf),

I still can't figure out how to simply pass two numbers to a `.sty`-file.

The situation is as follows: there is a `.sty`-file that changes the behaviour of `siunitx` so that only very small and very large numbers are output in scientific notation, and the other numbers are displayed in the usual format. This file has the following contents:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand*{\ThresholdLow}{0.01}
\newcommand*{\ThresholdHigh}{100}
\let\OldNum\num%
\renewcommand*{\num}[2][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\ThresholdLow}{%
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=\ThresholdHigh}{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
        }{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

and is for the time being saved as `threshold.sty` in the same folder as the (to be) compiled document. This document includes it using the `usepackage`-command, as such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threshold}
\newcommand{\Row}[1]{#1 & \OldNum{#1} & \num{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
    Num & Old & New\\\hline\\[-0.7em]
    \Row{0.01}\\
    \Row{0.1}\\
    \Row{1}\\
    \Row{10}\\
    \Row{100}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the `.sty`-file above, there are two lines defining the limits outside of which the numbers should be printed using scientific notation:

```
\newcommand*{\ThresholdLow}{0.01}
\newcommand*{\ThresholdHigh}{100}
```

Now ideally, these two thresholds would be given as an argument to the `threshold.sty` using for example

```
\usepackage[low=0.01,high=100]{threshold}
```

where the file would use `0.01` and `100` as default values if no arguments are given.

What is the preferred way to do this? And maybe more useful to other readers that are as new to these matters as I am: what would be the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By rereading the documentation of `kvoptions` once more, I figured it out myself. This is the result:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,kvoptions,siunitx}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=threshold,prefix=threshold@}
\DeclareStringOption[1]{low}[0.01]
\DeclareStringOption[1]{high}[100]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\OldNum\num%
\renewcommand*{\num}[2][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\threshold@low}{%
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=\threshold@high}{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
        }{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

First the options need to be set up using `\SetupKeyvalOptions`, then the keys (variables) are defined using `\DeclareStringOption`, and finally these keys are processed with `\ProcessKeyvalOptions*`. In my case this is done with the next piece of code.

```
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=threshold,prefix=threshold@}
\DeclareStringOption[1]{low}[0.01]
\DeclareStringOption[1]{high}[100]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
```

Here `\DeclareStringOption[1]{low}[0.01]` says for example that the key `low` has as initial value `1`, which changes to `0.01` if the key `low` is passed to the package without value (i.e. `\usepackage[low]{threshold}`), and otherwise the value that is assigned by calling the package (e.g. `\usepackage[low=1e-3]{threshold}`).
We can now use `\threshold@low` and `\threshold@high` as variables.

---

Using the same `.tex`-file as described in the question, we can now for example only use a threshold for the lower bound:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[low]{threshold}
\newcommand{\Row}[1]{#1 & \OldNum{#1} & \num{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
    Num & Old & New\\\hline\\[-0.7em]
    \Row{0.01}\\
    \Row{0.1}\\
    \Row{1}\\
    \Row{10}\\
    \Row{100}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using the default value for the lower threshold and using a different value for the higher threshold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[low,high=1e3]{threshold}
\newcommand{\Row}[1]{#1 & \OldNum{#1} & \num{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
    Num & Old & New\\\hline\\[-0.7em]
    \Row{0.01}\\
    \Row{0.1}\\
    \Row{1}\\
    \Row{10}\\
    \Row{100}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]